# SQL: Exchange column values

Tags: sql

Want to clear some concepts about SQL internals.

Suppose I have a table as:

```
---------tblXY-----------
X int
Y int
```

Now it has records as:

```
X Y
---
1 4
2 3
3 2
4 1
```

And I want the resulting table to be:

```
X Y
---
4 1
3 2
2 3
1 4
```

So I wrote the query as:

```
UPDATE tblXY   
 SET [X] = Y
 ,[Y] = X
```

and got the required result.

But how did it happened? I mean I'm setting X's value as Y's current value and at the very moment I'm setting Y's value as X's.

Comment: I have a similar problem with a WHERE clause. There it does not work, like desicribed. However, I have no solution for this yet.
Would something be like

UPDATE tblXY SET [X] = Y, [Y] = X WHERE X>2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because the operations are a single atomic action - the current values of `X` and `Y` are read first before any of the assignments are done.

So it's not so much:

```
for every row:
    set x = y
    set y = x
```

but more like:

```
for every row:
    set tmpx = x
    set tmpy = y
    set x = tmpy
    set y = tmpx
```

Keep in mind that's just the conceptual view. It's likely to be much more efficient under the covers.

Without that, you'd have to store the temporary yourself for every row, or just rename the columns :-)